# How can i revoke Yammer user via API?

Tags: yammer

I'm working on a solution (not a 3rd party app) that will force active Yammer user to re-authenticate via my Proxy. I have access only to Yammer API.
I would like to know if i can revoke active Yammer user using Yammer API in order to force him to authenticate again and to receive a new token from server?
Can i remove from admin the Auth token for specific user using API and that will force him to re-authenticate and then receive new auth token ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any API endpoint to force users to re-authenticate to your app. The options that I can think of are: 1. The user will have to manually revoke the app's access from his/her profile page. 2. Create a new app and update the app_id and secret_key in your code.  3. Although I have not tested it, disabling an app may cascade revoke all tokens that are associated with app; for this, you'd need to file a Support case and ask them to disable and re-enable your app.